# Coin flip command

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I started coding my first Discord bot yesterday, and already have a dice roll command, and now want a coin flip command.

How would I code this out?

Using Node.JS and Discord.JS library.

Comment: You make it generate a random number between 0 and 1. If its 0 its heads, if its 1 its tails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(command == "ht")
{
      function doRandHT() {
var rand = ['HEADS!','TAILS!'];

return rand[Math.floor(Math.random()*rand.length)];
}

 const embed = {
"title": `Here is the winner!`,
"description": doRandHT(),
"color": 7584788,
};
message.channel.send({ embed });


};
```

You can use this plain command for every random command in Discord.js I also integrated this with embed design so it will come in a well-designed box.

Warning: You may need to make changes in your code in order to get this working. Some uses different command structures, Don't expect it to work when you just paste it. Make changes, look to your other commands and make changes according to them.

This is fully tested and working random command.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your command, you can use this to generate a random number (`0` or `1`): [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) gives you a number between 0 and 1 (excluded), while [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) rounds that number to 0 or 1.

```
Math.round(Math.random()); //O or 1
```

Then you can use that number to send in the channel if it's heads or tails.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know something about JavaScript, go to [Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)

If you'd like to learn something about the Discord.js library, go to [the Discord.js Documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) and use the search bar in the top right.

```js
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    const bot = new Discord.Client({
      disableEveryone: true
    });

    //The 'message' event, emitted whenever somebody says something in a text channel
    bot.on('message', async koolMessage => {
      if (koolMessage.content.startsWith("coinflip")) {
        //If the message's content starts with "coinflip" run the following:
        let outcomes = ["Heads", "Tails"];
        //An array that has the possible outcomes from flipping a coin, heads and tails
        let outcomesIndex = Math.round(Math.random() * outcomes.length);
        //This will be what index of the outcomes array should be selected (arrays start at 0)
        //Math.round() rounds the parameter inside, in this case, Math.random()
        koolMessage.channel.send(outcomes[outcomesIndex]);
        //'koolMessage' is what we decided to call the message in the 'message' event, above. It can be called whatever you'd like
        //'channel' is the text channel in which 'koolMessage' was sent
        //The send() function sends a message with the included argument (e.g. send("hello there!")). It must be sent in a channel, in this case, the channel in which the 'koolMessage' from the user was sent
        //If we would have outcomes[0], the output would be "Heads", if we would have outcomes[1] the output would be "Tails", so we randomize it, giving us either outcomes[0] or outcomes[1]
      }
    });

    bot.login('YOUR TOKEN');
```

Comment: Man this code is not executable, you shouldn't use a code snippet. Instead, use a code sample, like the one I used in the edit you deleted.